# react-static: ReferenceError while building

Tags: reactjs, react-static

This error occurs when a project is build.

I think it's because I don't have a react-static build, but I don't know the error.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-static": "^7.2.0",
    "react-static-plugin-reach-router": "^7.2.0",
    "react-static-plugin-sass": "^7.2.2",
    "react-static-plugin-sitemap": "^7.2.0",
    "react-static-plugin-source-filesystem": "^7.2.0",
    ....
  },
```

build command:
**yarn build**

*(but react-static build command is **react-static build**)*

**error**

```
ReferenceError: Failed exporting HTML for URL / (/Users/youj/projects/project_name/src/pages/index.js): document is   not defined

  - aos.js:1 n
    [project_name]/[aos]/dist/aos.js:1:14577

  - aos.js:1 Object._ [as init]
    [project_name]/[aos]/dist/aos.js:1:1530

  - static-app.js:1850 MainFunction
    /Users/youj/projects/project_name/artifacts/static-app.js:1850:26

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36 d
    [project_name]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:498

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:39 Za
    [project_namee]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:39:16

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44 a.b.render
    [project_name]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:476

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44 a.b.read
    [project_name]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:44:18

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:54 renderToString
    [project_name]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:54:364

  - exportRoute.js:137 renderToStringAndExtract
    [project_name]/[react-static]/src/static/exportRoute.js:137:21

  - exportRoute.js:194 _callee$
    [project_name]/[react-static]/src/static/exportRoute.js:194:15
```

**tree**

```
├──src
   ├──index.js (render app.js)
   ├── pages
   │   ├── 404.js
   │   └── index.js (call view components)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is aos error!

This has been settled.

```
if (process.browser) {
  AOS.init({
    duration: 600,
    easing: 'ease-in-cubic', 
    delay: 1200,
    anchorPlacement: 'bottom-bottom',
  });
}
```